# Do you need to sign physically on stamps in your contract other than dedicated sign places?

Tags: legal, taxes

I know the following points, as a buyer

1. To get stamp duty, before executing the contract.
2. Sign off the contract.

But I am not sure whether I need to sign my signature above stick stamps during signing off, as additional to dedicated sign places of contract. I am just start up my own company with my friends, and not so familiar with contracting, and one of my friend said me to sign physically on the stamps too.

Can anyone explain me what is the standard operation procedure?

Comment: In what country?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There can be instances where you sign over a stamp. I have done this may times as a part of signing many contacts. Its normal to do so.

Context: Startup related contacts in India.